# Need control over TaskPane from CustomTab Word Web Add-in

Tags: javascript, office-js, office-addins, word-web-addins

I am developing a Word Web Add-in with a CustomTab and a TaskPane.
From the Manifest.xml file I am triggering events to JavaScript function through `ExecuteFunction`
JS function is getting hit, but there is no update happening on the TaskPane UI

**Manifest.xml**

```
<FunctionFile resid="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" />
<bt:Urls>
    <bt:Url id="Contoso.FunctionFile.Url" DefaultValue="~remoteAppUrl/Home.html" />
</bt:Urls>
<Action xsi:type="ExecuteFunction">
    <FunctionName>appendText</FunctionName>
</Action>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function appendText() {
    var count = 10;
    $("#main").append(count);
}
```

**HTML**

`<div style="width:100%" id="main"></div>`

Same JQuery function is working in normal button click function call, which exist inside the TaskPane.

How can I trigger events that should execute properly ?

Answer (score 0):

The function file HTML, and the JavaScript file that it calls, run in a completely separate execution context from the task pane. If I understand what you've done, you have set the home.html as your FunctionFile *and* as the task pane home page. If you do this, you are loading a *second copy* of home.html when the FunctionFile is invoked, (and the second copy will be invisible, I think, because the function file never shows a UI). Your append method is working on the second instance of the page, not the instance in the task pane.

The best way that I can think of to communicate from the function file (which should be UI-less page) to the task pane is to use LocalStorage. Your appendText method should store the value "10" in LocalStorage with a key such as "count". JavaScript in your task pane needs to read "count" from LocalStorage and append it's value to #main.

If you need this to happen in an automatic manner, then the code in the task pane that's checking "count" in LocalStorage should run in a timed loop.

**UPDATE 6/16/18:** 
In response to OP's comment: 
There are two different execution contexts at work here; that is, two different instances of Internet Explorer and it's embedded JavaScript engine:

First, there is a home page for the task pane, home.html. It has a UI and it loads JavaScript.

Second, there is the FunctionFile.html that is launched by the ribbon button. This should be a *different HTML page* than the home page of the task pane. This page should have no UI; no visible HTML elements in its body. It should load JavaScript. This should be a different JS file from the one loaded by the task pane's home page. You don't want to load two copies of the same file. When this page is called, no IE window or task pane opens. It is never seen.

These two instances of IE are unknown to each other. They can communicate only by writing and reading to the machine's local storage. For this reason, if you want JavaScript that is invoked by the button on your custom tab to change DOM elements in the page in the task pane, you can only do that by passing a signal through LocalStorage.

The JavaScript loaded by the FunctionFile.html should store the "count" value in LocalStorage and *do nothing more*. JavaScript in this file cannot address DOM elements in the home page because that DOM is in a completely different instance of IE.

The JavaScript loaded by the home page, should read the "count" value from LocalStorage and append it to the `#main` element in the home page's DOM.

So, the JavaScript that writes to LocalStorage and the JavaScript that reads LocalStorage are in different functions, in different JavaScript files, running in different instances of IE.

If you haven't already please see [Add-in Commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/add-in-commands) and [Step 6 of Excel tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/tutorials/excel-tutorial?tutorial-step=6).

Comment: So I changed the appendText method like below: `var count = 10;
    if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {

        localStorage.setItem("count", count);

        var s = localStorage.getItem("count");
        console.log(s);
        $("#main").append(s); 
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Not supported";
    }`   but I am not getting the event execution, Is there anything to change in my code ? I am new to this, can you explain please ?